# set a 1 second gap inside load() function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using jquery load() to load some files.

I need to have a 1 second gap each time the `myfuc()` is called inside this load() function.

This is what I did. Currently it doesn't call `myfuc()` every 1 second, it calls `myfuc()` 9 times at the same time.

My requirement is to call `myfuc()` when each html file if fully loaded.
or
To call `myfuc()` with a 1 second gap

```
for(i = 1; i < 10; i++){
   $('#wrapper' + i ).load('some'+i+'.html', function(index) {
      setTimeout(function() {
         myfuc();
      }, 1000 * (index + 1));
   });
}
```

Comment: its a problem of scope, you can use ES6 let `for (let i=0; i < 10; i++)` or an IIFE to control variable scope.

Comment: @NaorTorgeman Thanks. Can you explain a bit more? I'm not following you.

Comment: Its not problem of scope, and he cant use ES6 in browser.

Comment: it might not be a scope problem, but yes he can :o http://caniuse.com/#feat=let

Comment: anyway most of ES6 is already implemented in modern browsers - https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/

Answer (score 0):

setInterval(myFunc, 1000);

Try this!

Answer (score 0):

```
// Select all images and for each
$('[id^="wrapper"]').each(function(idx) {
    // ... register listening on load event...
    var i = idx + 1;
    $(this).load('some'+i+'.html', function() {
        // ...and if particular image is loaded, start timer...
        setTimeout(function() {
        // ...which fires this func
            myfuc();
       }, 1000 * i);
    });
});
```

If you explicitly need read var i from tag id

```js
function myFunc(i) {
  console.log("Image with id wrapper"+i+" loaded"); 
}

$('[id^="wrapper"]').each( function() {  
  var i = parseInt($(this).prop("id").substring(7),10) ; 
  $(this).load('some'+i+'.html', function() {    
    setTimeout(function() {
      myFunc(i);
    }, 1000 * i);    
  });  
});
```

```html
<img src="http://placehold.it/100/60?text=Image 1" id="wrapper1">
<img src="http://placehold.it/100/60?text=Image 2" id="wrapper2">
<img src="http://placehold.it/100/60?text=Image 3" id="wrapper3">
<img src="http://placehold.it/100/60?text=Image 4" id="wrapper4">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: THanks. What if I'm using the `i` in 2 different places? e.g. `$('#wrapper' + i ).load('some'+i+'.html', function(index) {` ?

Comment: Also with `$('[id^="wrapper"]')` , how do I know $('wrapper1') has `some1.html` loaded in it?

Comment: Wait, Im adding new example

Comment: Edited. Is this what you want?

Answer (score -1):

it can be a scope problem - the set timeout gets the same i every time.

you can try solving it with the let variable

```
   for(let i = 1; i < 10; i++){
       $('#wrapper' + i ).load('some'+i+'.html', function(i) {
           setTimeout(function() {
               myfuc();
           }, 1000 * (i+ 1));
       });
   }
```

or with an IIFE

```
   for(var i = 1; i < 10; i++){
       (function (index) {
           $('#wrapper' + index).load('some'+index+'.html', function(index) {
               setTimeout(function() {
                   myfuc();
               }, 1000 * (index+ 1));
           });
       })(i);
   }
```

Comment: Thanks. Why use `i` inside `function(i)` ?

Comment: I edited it to make it more clear, in order to keep the right value of variable i i'm passing it as a value to the self invoked function. [you can read more about it here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/592396/what-is-the-purpose-of-a-self-executing-function-in-javascript)